# IOS/Objective-C: Conflicting return type in implementation error

Tags: ios, objective-c, int

Can anyone suggest why following is giving warning of Conflicting return type in implementation error myStatus level void vs. int, what this means, and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
-(int) myStatusLevel: (int)numpoints {
    //calculates status from points and saves in default.
    int status;
    if (numpoints>=20&&numpoints<=99) {
        status = 1;
    }
    else if (numpoints>=100&&numpoints<=499) {
        status = 2;
    }
    else if (numpoints>=500&&numpoints<=999) {
        status = 3;
    }
    else if (numpoints>=1000&&numpoints<=1999) {
        status = 4;
    }
    else if (numpoints>=2000) {
        status = 5;
    }
    else {
        status = 0;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: @Rob that was it.  Thanks.  How do I simplify using that link?

Comment: Oh.  Understood.  I actually had it along those lines at first but added the explicit upper and lower boundaries as I thought that might be causing error.  Good to confirm that they are not needed as the code is simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have likely defined `myStatusLevel` in your `@interface` with `void`, rather than the method signature you've shared with us here.